# Difference between KB before you write on the file and After you write on the file

Tags: c#, string

I am currently working on a list of strings `List<string>` datavalue which hold delimited values inside, I tried to compute for the KB using this function `int strlen = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(datavalues.ToString());` and I am getting a value of 48 in my Strlen variable. after I write the datavalue list of string into a text file, the size of the file that generated was 2430 kb. how big is the difference when you have the size of a list of string and when you write it? is there some characters being added afterwards which makes the output file big?

Comment: I believe this is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470787/please-help-me-understand-size-vs-size-on-disk

Comment: When you call ToString on a list it is going to give you "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" which is 48 bytes in UTF8.

Comment: That's the name of the type.  Sure, "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" is 48 bytes long.  Doesn't have anything to do with the size of the strings in the list of course.

Answer (score 5):

A `List<String>` (which is what your variable `datavalues` is) will output the following when `ToString` is called:

> System.Collections.Generic.List[String] (or something like that)

Which is approximately 48 bytes long. The actual **contents** of the strings are not included. To get the full length, you would need to do something like:

```
String.Join("", dataValues.ToArray()).Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

`datavalues.ToString` is the string representation of the list itself. If you want the size of all the strings in the list you can do something like:

```
var len = datavalues.Sum(l => Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(l));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is vastly inaccurate. Following would be better

```
long size = 0;
object o = new object();
using (Stream s = new MemoryStream()) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, o);
    size = s.Length;
}
```

Note also that my disc allocation size is 4096 bytes.

[image]

File can only allocates space where **file_content_size <= n * allocation_size**.

Note also that in UTF8 some characters are stored with **1 byte** and others with **6 bytes**!